# How to import python packages without pip install

Tags: python

The server that I am using has an older version of python installed, and I am unable to install packages. Is there a workaround to importing python modules? If I can create my own module and append the directory to be able to import the newly created module, then I am assuming that I should be able to do the same for already built packages. I just need to know how I would be able to install what is required for numpy and then import it using a similar method as when creating modules.

Comment: A module like `numpy` is not pure Python, as it also contains native code extensions. So you probably won't be able to install it on a machine that doesn't have a compiler.

Comment: Have you tried using `easy_install` in place of `pip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you find a machine to install the same version of Python to match your server.  Perform the pip install from that stand alone machine.  Do some level of testing to make sure that the code with run with that version of Python and everything is happy.   Just the other day I found out the hard way that TensorFlow would now work on the latest Python.

The libraries are being installed for me under `c:\users\<profilename>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages`  So you could then copy that over to the server.

I found this link that is saying the same thing.

https://superuser.com/questions/943980/is-it-possible-to-install-python-packages-without-a-direct-outbound-network-conn

Good Luck with it.